# DOM manipulation in codeigniter before page loads

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

is there a way to modify the html of a view file before or as it is loaded, such that a containing div element can be wrapped around existing elements that have a particular class.

So as an example:

if i have the element

```
<div class="add-wrapper-to-this-elem">

</div>
```

somewhere within the view file test_view.php, when i load the view via `$this->load->view('test_view');` i would then like the view to load with an extra wrapper div around all elements with the class of add-wrapper-to-elem

is this possible and how would i go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper view file with content and load this view instead:

```
<div class="add-wrapper-to-this-elem">
          <?php $this->load->view('test_view');?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Processing Output](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#output) on the CodeIgniter docs.

You can use the _output function to get rendered HTML in your controller and then use matching (regex or otherwise) to find your elements and wrap them.

See [Using regular expressions to extract content on askaboutphp.](http://www.askaboutphp.com/25/regex-extract-content.html)

Comment: [Don't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), use an XML parser like [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)